# PDF Text Font size Increase-decrease

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I have to integrate PDF file in my iPad Application. So now, is it possible to increase-decrease font size of that PDF document.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible to increase or decrease the font size of PDF but you can zoom in or zoom out the page because pdf open as a Image.

If you are using ePub file format then you can increase or decrease the font size because it's open as a HTML.